# Haproxy log file with pfsense

Tags: haproxy, log-files, pfsense

I am trying to read the `/var/log/haproxy.log` file with the command: `clog -f haproxy.log` but nothing happens. No window opens. How do I see my error log? I’m on pfsense.

Answer (score 2):

First you have to activate the logs in the settings.

Services -> HAProxy -> Settings, "Logging" section.

In "Remote syslog host" put `/var/run/log`.

Save and apply. Now `clog -f /var/log/haproxy.log` you should give you something.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works !!!

Comment: @JeanMarkOrfali please also accept the answer (and upvote). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to enable local logs on HAProxy at pfSense 2.7.0, I had to edit the `/etc/defaults/rc.conf` file and change the `syslogd_flags` line to allow the syslog to listen on UDP socket as cited on [FreeBSD Forums](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/haproxy-not-logging.76876/#post-477067):

```
syslogd_flags="-s -b localhost -C"
```

I'd rebooted the system and changed the HAProxy settings to the same as recommended by @DeepBlueMussel and it worked as expected.

You can also check HAProxy logs on pfSense UI (Stats > System Logs > Packages > haproxy).

To display detailed information specific to a particular frontend (eg URLs accessed by the client), enable the "**Detailed Log**" checkbox in the frontend configuration.